# How to prevent nvidia-auto-select switch to incorrect resolution at login screen?

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, xorg.conf

I have a small issue when starting up my machine into Ubuntu. Everything goes smoothly, the login screen appears at the correct resolution. Then it switches to an incorrect resolution, after I login the resolution resolves it self correctly again.

I've followed various threads dealing with nvidia driver issues (I originally started with black screen after getting a new graphics card). With this latest issue I've been through the Xorg.0.log and identified two points that reflect the changes in resolution.

The first part seems to configure the correct resolution

```
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     3.428] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     3.428] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     3.428] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "Stereo" "0"
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "SLI" "Off"
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MultiGPU" "Off"
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "BaseMosaic" "off"
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Stereo disabled by request
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA SLI disabled.
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA Multi-GPU disabled.
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "1920x1080 +0+0"
[     3.428] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     4.047] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[     4.047] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[     4.047] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[     4.047] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[     4.047] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[     4.047] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[     4.047] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4 (boot)
[     4.049] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: disconnected
[     4.049] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     4.049] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: disconnected
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     4.051] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[     4.052] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     4.052] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[     4.052] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     4.052] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[     4.082] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-4: connected
[     4.082] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[     4.082] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     4.082] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[     4.082] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20150116)
[     4.082] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 970 (GM204-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[     4.082] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 4194304 kBytes
[     4.082] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 84.04.36.00.5e
[     4.082] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     4.082] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[     4.082] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device DFP-4 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[     4.082] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[     4.087] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[     4.087] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "1920x1080+0+0"
[     4.087] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[     4.095] (WW) NVIDIA(0): DFP-4 does not have an EDID, or its EDID does not contain a
[     4.095] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     maximum image size; cannot compute DPI from DFP-4's EDID.
[     4.095] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[     4.095] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     4.096] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[     4.096] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[     4.118] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1920x1080+0+0"
[     4.166] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[     4.166] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[     4.166] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     4.166] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
```

Then a bit further on it appears to get reset

```
[     7.343] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[     7.343] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.343] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.346] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.376] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: connected
[     7.376] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[     7.376] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.376] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.407] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[     7.463] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select @1024x768 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1024x768, ViewPortOut=1024x768+0+0}"
[     7.566] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[     7.566] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.566] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.568] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.569] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     7.569] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[     7.569] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.569] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.598] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: connected
[     7.598] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[     7.598] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.598] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Then further on around the point that I log on, it corrects again

```
[    21.754] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[    21.755] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    21.755] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    21.757] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    21.787] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: connected
[    21.787] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    21.787] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    21.787] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    21.935] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DVI-D-0: 1920x1080 @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[    22.028] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[    22.028] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.028] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.030] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.034] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.035] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    22.035] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    22.035] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.035] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.064] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: connected
[    22.064] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    22.064] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.064] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.067] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[    22.067] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.067] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.069] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    22.099] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: connected
[    22.099] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    22.099] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    22.099] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

I'm not sure where the configuration is that triggers the nvidia-auto-select, or even if this can be adjusted. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

### EDIT 1

xorg.conf file as requested

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 361.42  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-13)  Tue Mar 22 18:36:23 PDT 2016

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 361.42  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-13)  Tue Mar 22 18:37:28 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DFP-4"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 970"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    Modes      "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a xorg.conf at all? Maybe there are some incorrect settings in there that might cause it to try and set a resolution it doesn't actually support.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the xorg.conf file for your perusal

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue too. Some desktop environment configs will override xorg.conf settings and show up as "nvidia-auto-select" in the log. In my case KDE had the resolution set in ~/.local/share/kscreen/*

You can confirm that its stored in a local config by creating and logging in with a new user. After that just set the screen resolution to some obscure width/height and grep for those numbers under ~/ to find where the config is hiding